# image change when click another button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am writing code for a puzzle matching game. I defined a `UIButton` with an `UIImage`, I added a target to change the `UIImage` of a `UIButton`. 
I want this photo to appear until I click another `UIButton` or the same `UIButton`, how can I do that ?!

the `UIButton`

```
mybutton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[mybutton1 addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(method:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
question = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puzzle.jpg"];
[mybutton1 setBackgroundImage:question 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

then the method:

```
-(void) method: (UIButton*) sender{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"cheerful-cat.jpg"] 
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way..

```
Button*  mybutton1= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[mybutton1 addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(method:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
question = [UIImage imageNamed:@"puzzle.jpg"];
[mybutton1 setBackgroundImage:question 
                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

-(void) method: (UIButton*) sender{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"cheerful-cat.jpg"] 
                      forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: change the button type `Custom` instead of `RoundRect`

Comment: no it doesnt work, thank u anyway,,
you know what i mean,, am trying to make photo memory game, how it flips the photo then when they dont match they were flipped again!
do u have any idea about that?!